# ¿Cómo se puede extraer una cadena de caracteres específica con Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Buen día Developers.

Estoy iniciándome con Pandas en Python, y por más que he buscado no encuentro la forma de extraer de una celda de un Data Frame ciertos caracteres:

Ejemplo:

tengo una fecha que es 20220215 y quiero pasarla a un formato que se pueda leer mejor, es decir, quiero pasarla a este formato 15/02/2022

En SQL lo haría así:
set fecha_nueva = rigth(fecha,2)&'/'&mid(fecha,5,2)&'/'&left(fecha,4) : 15/02/2022

pero quiero hacer esto mismo con Pandas y no encuentro la forma.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes leer y escribir el valor de una celda con iloc. Si por ejemplo quieres modificar el formato de la posición 2, 3 de tu dataframe harías algo así:

```py
from datetime import datetime

df.iloc[2, 3] = datetime.strptime(df.iloc[2, 3], '%Y%m%d').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

---

**Respuesta original**

Puedes convertirlo directamente a objeto datetime con [`pandas.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) especificando el formato con `format='%Y%m%d'`

```
df['Fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Fecha'], format='%Y%m%d')
```

Si lo quieres específicamente en formato dd/mm/yyyy puedes convertir ese objeto datetime a string con `strftime` igual que harías con datetime:

```
df['Fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Fecha'], format='%Y%m%d').dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: Gracias Cesar, si me funcionó, creo que es una manera correcta de dar formato de a la fecha y así cumplo con lo que requiero. Pero en el caso de que sea sólo un texto el que quiero cambiar, como podría cambiar o extraer una cadena de texto de cada celda?, lo puedo hacer con una variable, pero directo del frame no se como hacerlo :(.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es modificar el contenido de una "celda" concreta la lógica es la misma, solo que accedes a ella con `.iloc`, voy a modificar la respuesta para darte uun poco más de luz al respecto